# Lost OnChange after form Validation

Tags: validation, forms, codeigniter, onchange

I'm using codeigniter and when selecting a dropdown form onchange works and i get my second field ok(Country->City).
When i submit the form with errors, the page reloads with the errors displayed but my onchange stops working.
Any ideas for what's going on?
Hmm, here's what i'm doing. User get's to homepage and fills the form, the onchange is working. User then submits the form with an error and i check the validation and load a new page(register) with the same onchange function. I tried to change the function name (getLocal) to another name but the result is the same. Tried to use live.("change", getLocal) and the result is the same, no firing on the register page...

```
 
function getLocal(){
    $("#city").load("home/ajaxlocal", {country: $(this).val()} );
   //alert($(this).val());

    return false;
}

..............

$js = 'id="country"';
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#country select").bind("change", getLocal);
        });
    
td echo form_label('Country :', $country); 
td id="country">echo form_dropdown('country', $country,$ct,$js);
```

Comment: Please make it clear which language your different code snippets are in. It's confusing to jump from javascript to a bit of ci_php mixed up with some html!

Answer (score 1):

IF yo arent reloading the page, but reloading elements with AJAX, the jquery will not bind to those new elements if you specify them in the ready() function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#country select").bind("change", getLocal);
});
```

This is loading this onload - try using .live()

http://api.jquery.com/live/

> This method is a variation on the basic .bind() method for attaching event handlers to elements. When .bind() is called, the elements that the jQuery object refers to get the handler attached; elements that get introduced later do not, so they would require another .bind() call.

Comment: Hmm, here's what i'm doing. user get's to homepage and fills the form, the onchange is working. User then submits the form with an error and i check the validation and load a new page(register) with the same onchange function. I tried to change the function name (getLocal) to another name but the result is the same. Tried to use live.("change", getLocal) and the result is the same, no firing on the register page

Comment: Can you post us your complete code for both the homepage and register page, plus you ci controllers and your jquery script? It's a bit difficult to see exactly what's going on at the moment...

Comment: Well, now I feel stupid...
Just forgot to add the id="country" to this line on the register page: td id="country">echo form_dropdown('country', $country,$ct,$js);

Sorry for waisting your time :(